# Python: Creating a Key

Tags: python, arrays

First time coding in Python. I am used to PHP and javascript.

```
 for CDuser6Minutes in CDusers6Minutes[minutetocheckpre]:
            if CDuser6Minutes in CDusers:
                if AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]:
                    AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes] = AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]+1
                else:
                    AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes] = 1
```

CDuser6Minutes are strings. In this case: "Mingodalia". Error I get is:

```
  File "...app.py", line 72, in <module>
    if AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]:
KeyError: 'Mingodalia'
```

Comment: So, `CDuser6Minutes` is indeed in `CDusers` (that's what you're checking on the line `if CDuser6Minutes in CDusers`) , but not in `AltsPre`. I suggest you do `if CDuser6Minutes in AltsPre` instead of `if AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]` Or even better, use the mighty [`collections.defaultdict(int)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Change your `if` to: `if CDuser6Minutes in AltsPre`

Comment: I havent been clear about what I want. I want the key "mingodalia" as the key in the array AltsPre.

Comment: This wouldn't work in PHP or Javascript either. For one thing, you've overwritten the name `CDuser6Minutes` so that it no longer refers to your original dict.

Comment: One isCDuser6Minutes and the other is isCDusersr6Minutes. I assume there isn't a "for two thing".

Comment: instead of all `if AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]:`  use  `AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes] = AltsPre.setdefault(CDuser6Minutes,0)+1`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your code by adding `CDuser6Minutes in AltsPre` to your second if statement.

Now what this does is that it will 1st check if the key exists in the dictionary and then check your condition `AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]`, which I am assuming you are using as a **truthy** condition.

So now once the execution reaches the condition `CDuser6Minutes in AltsPre` it will **short circuit** at that condition and not execute `AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]`, directly going the else statement.

thus your modified code will look like this -

```
for CDuser6Minutes in CDusers6Minutes[minutetocheckpre]:
        if CDuser6Minutes in CDusers:
            if CDuser6Minutes in AltsPre and AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]:
                AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes] = AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]+1
            else:
                AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes] = 1
```

the error you are getting right now is because your code assumes that key **Mingodalia** exists in **AltsPre** because `AltsPre[CDuser6Minutes]` is a lookup into the dictionary **AltsPre**

Let me know in comments, for any further clarifications.